# How to download Artifactory from JFrog Artifactory via terminal?

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am working on Jenkinsfile and for the project I need to get some Artifactory, can anyone help me with the correct command?

I was thinking about curl but then it is asking me for username and password, follow by a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stage in your Jenkinsfile, use your download command within a `withCredentials` directive.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'artifactoryCredentials', passwordVariable: 'ART_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'ART_USERNAME')]) {
    sh 'curl -u ${ART_USERNAME}:${ART_PASSWORD} https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/com/projectA/wrapper/app-1.0.jar'
}
```

If you're using `wget` to download your packages, use the below within `sh` block.

```sh
wget --user ${ART_USERNAME} --password ${ART_PASSWORD} https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/com/projectA/wrapper/app-1.0.jar
```

Please check with the Admin on the right `credentialsId` to use within your Jenkins pipeline.

For more info on handling credentials refer [Jenkinsfile documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials).